# Weird behavior of for loops in specific conditions. Processing

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, processing

I'm learning how to use processing and tried to make a simple snake game, while doing it it does show (although it was cntrl+c cntrl+v from the first one, which was up) a Weir behavior in for loops specifically for going right or down.

i managed to fix the 'down' problem by simply changing 
      for(int k=0;k<56;k++)
to 
      for(int k=55;k<=0;k--) 
which is exactly the same thing, isn't it? i am i missing something?

```
    int [][] snakeHead = new int[60][60];

    int game = 1;
    int value = 0;

    String s = "You lost\nPress SHIFT to Restart";

    void setup(){

    size(600,600);
    frameRate(10);

    for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
      for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
        snakeHead[i][k] = 0;
      }
    }
    snakeHead[1][22] = 1;
    game = 1;
    value = 0;

    }

    void draw(){
      background(0);
      fill(255);
      rect(20, 20, 560, 560);

    if(game == 1){
      for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
          if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1){
            fill(0,255,0);
            rect(20+i*10, 20+k*10, 10,10);
          }
        }
      }
      if(value == 1){
        up();
      }else if(value == 2){
        down();
      }else if(value == 3){
        left();
      }else if(value == 4){
        right();
      }
    }
    else{
      textSize(32);
      textAlign(CENTER);
      fill(0,0,255);
      text(s, 300, 300);
    }
    }

    void keyPressed(){
      if(key == CODED){

        if(keyCode == UP){
          value = 1;
          }
        else if(keyCode == DOWN){
          value = 2;
        }
        else if(keyCode == LEFT){
          value = 3;
        }
        else if(keyCode == RIGHT){
          value = 4;

        }else if(keyCode == SHIFT){
            setup();
        }
    }
    }

    void up(){

      for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
          if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && k == 0){
            game = 0;
          }else if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1){
            snakeHead[i][k-1] = 1;
            snakeHead[i][k]=0;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void down(){

      for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
          if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && k == 55){
            game = 0;

          }else if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && k != 55){
            snakeHead[i][k+1] = 1;
            snakeHead[i][k] = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void right(){

      for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
          if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i == 55){
            game = 0;
          }else if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i != 55){
            snakeHead[i+1][k] = 1;
            snakeHead[i][k]=0;
          }
        }
      }

    }
    void left(){
      for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
          if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i == 0){
            game = 0;
          }else if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1){
            snakeHead[i-1][k] = 1;
            snakeHead[i][k]=0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: sorry for redundancy on specifically void right() and void down(), i was trying idk... to fix it :P

Comment: `for(int k=55;k<=0;k--)` isn't the same as `for(int k=0;k<56;k++)`. The latter will run 56 times; the former won't run at all.

Comment: for some weird reason it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in the right and down that in both you update the head **down** the loop  (with `i+1 or j+1`) so the else block get execute more then once (in the `up` and `left` you doing `i-1` and `j-1` so it doesn't happens there).

Let look at the `right` function to demonstrate:

```
void right(){
    for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
            if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i == 55){
                game = 0;
            } else if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i != 55){
                snakeHead[i+1][k] = 1; // update the sankeHead to i+1 which will be reached in the next iteration in i so basiclly keep moving right till reach if block 
                snakeHead[i][k]=0;
            }
        } // end k loop
    } // end i loop
}
```

To fix this all you need to do is add **`return`** because you only want to move the snakeHead **once**!

so:

```
void right(){
    for(int i=0;i<56;i++){
        for(int k=0;k<56;k++){
            if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i == 55){
                game = 0;
                return;
            } else if(snakeHead[i][k] == 1 && i != 55){
                snakeHead[i+1][k] = 1; 
                snakeHead[i][k]=0;
                return;
            }
        } // end k loop
    } // end i loop
}
```